# Atbash cipher in Ruby

Tags: algorithm, ruby, cryptography

I implemented my own spin on the Atbash cipher in Ruby:

---

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Cryptorb
  # The Atbash cipher 
  module Atbash
    module_function

    # Encrypts a string
    #
    # @param plaintext [String] the message that will be encrypted
    #
    # @return [String] the encrypted message
    def encrypt(plaintext:)
      atbash(plaintext)
    end

    # Decrypts an encrypted string
    #
    # @param ciphertext [String] the encrypted message that will be decrypted
    #
    # @return [String] the decrypted message
    def decrypt(ciphertext:)
      atbash(ciphertext)
    end

    # The algorithm
    def atbash(string)
      cap_a, cap_z = 65, 90
      a, z = 97, 122

      ciphertext = string.chars.map do |char|
        limits = [cap_a, cap_z] if char.ord.between?(cap_a, cap_z)
        limits = [a, z] if char.ord.between?(a, z)

        limits ? (limits.last - (char.ord - limits.first)).chr : char
      end

      ciphertext.join
    end

    private_class_method :atbash
  end
end
```

---

White-space and numbers should not be modified. Character case should remain the same.

**For example:**

- `"1"` should map to `"1"`
- `"."` should map to `"."`
- `"B"` should map to `"Y"`
- `"b"` should map to `"y"`

**Note:** This implementation does not follow the "official" mathematical function of the Atbash cipher (`E(x) = (-x mod m) + 1`). Do you think it would be better if it did?

[Here's](https://repl.it/repls/RecentMonstrousOffice) a REPL if you want to test it online.